# JavaScript error when using Creo Software

Tags: javascript, windows

I have been having trouble with my Creo Parametric 3.0. As soon as the application loads up, am getting a window called "script error" popping up and no matter how I try to close it, it keeps recurring, disabling me to use the software. I have tried installing the entire software again and is of no use.

I have attached an image capturing the above mentioned problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is related with the Creo's internal browser and the page you are visiting.
In creo 3.0 (and later) the variable `windows_browser_type` (at config.pro) can be set to  `ie_process`(default value) or `chromium_browser`.
If set to `chromium_browser` the errors will not appear.